# How to setup Pi with a mdns address other than .local?

Tags: networking, pi-4, dns, docker

### hardware

- Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Lite

### Purpose

I already have an IoT Stack comprising of InfluxDB, Telegraf, Mosquitto, Grafana running on the Pi via `docker` (`docker-compose` more precisely) and wish to pack the stack behind a reverse-proxy using `traefik`.

In order to set rules for the Grafana Frontend, I wish to make it available when one hits `grafana.mypi4.lan` or something similar since I do not have a Domain Name as all the development is for test purposes.

AFAIK `mypi4.local` is an FQDN under mDNS but something like `traefik.mypi4.local` or `grafana.mypi4.local` is not an FQDN.

Is there a way to change the domain name in order to test the reverse-proxy I wish to setup for my Pi?

At Work, we already have our own domain and nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
domain workplace.domain.de
nameserver <IP_1>
nameserver <IP_2>
```

I tried changing the `/etc/hosts` to

```
127.0.1.1 mypi4-traefik.workplace.domain.de mypi4-traefik
```

as well as the `hostname` of the pi to `mypi4-traefik`

the pi is reachable via my Windows 10 laptop on the `.local` domain name but not on `mpi4-traefik.workplace.domain.de`

Comment: In my experience you can, but I am not a Windows user.  Technically [the spec requires this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS#Protocol_overview) *(meaning, mdns is only supposed to work with `.local`).*  I think while the linux implementation doesn't enforce it, the one on Windows does.

Comment: I mean at the end of the day it really doesn't matter if it is windows or not, since whatever will be served is a via a Webbrowser and plus there is WSL if there ever needs to be some form of UNIX-y client.

Comment: If this is for testing, manually associate that domain name with the Pi's LAN address: https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/edit-hosts-file/ (I haven't tried this as again I'm not a user, but it was found instantly via web search for  "windows hardcode dns").

Comment: You changed the resolve.conf on the raspi, right? Then you made the new FQNs visible only for the raspi. It's a local configuration, The Windows laptop has no access to it. The mdns entry (*.local) is not a normal name resolution. It's generated and distributed automatically through a different protocol. I'm not a Windows user, but there is surely a similar "resolve.conf" where you can enter the external IP of the raspi with some FQNs you'd like to access it with. My english is horrible, but I hope you get the idea. By the way 127.0.1.1 is a really strange localhost ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Both `mypi4.local` , `traefik.mypi4.local` and `grafana.mypi4.local` is a FQDN (Fully Quallified Domain Name).

See under example, what a FQDN consist of : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

You have to add to either a local DNS server or a host file for `traefik.mypi4.local` and `grafana.mypi4.local` to the machine you are testing from.

But I would avoid using `.local` in the hosfile, just to separate mDNS from local host resolution, so use something else!

Windows hostfile (example:  `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`).